# Creating custom internet gateway

Tags: networking, network-programming

Suppose I have an internet connection from an ISP and the internet can be shared to others through a wifi-router. How do I create my own gateway before users can access the internet. Also can I create a web application for monitoring internet traffic of different users connected to the wifi. All the traffic data must be synced to a web server. Do I require any extra hardware apart from the wifi-router?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is all about networking; it may be relevant for Network Engineering Stack Exchange!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, it does appear off-topic here, but a Wi-Fi router is probably a consumer-grade device, and that would be off-topic for [networkengineering.se]. It is probably more appropiate for [su].